# Use JavaScript checkbox value in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms, paypal

I'd like to be able to use a total amount generated using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)and displayed on the page in a `<span>` field later on in an HTML form. The checkbox additions and subtractions work correctly, I have no issue with that. What I have not been able to figure out is how to use that value later on in an HTML field (shown below as the PayPal code).

I have this in the `<head>` which handles the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript):

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var total = 0.00;

    function test(item) {
      if (item.checked) {
        total += parseFloat(item.value);
      } else {
        total -= parseFloat(item.value);
      }
      //alert(total);
      document.getElementById('Totalcost').innerHTML = total.toFixed(2);
    }
  </script>
</head>
```

The this `adds`/`subtracts` if a check box is checked:

```
<td class="column-3">
  <br>
  <label class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Shoes" value="2.95" onClick="test(this);">Select<span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
</td>
<td class="column-3">
  <br>
  <label class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Clothes" value="2.95" onClick="test(this);">Select<span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
</td>
```

Then I display the total with this:

```
Total Amount: $<span id="Totalcost">0.00</span>
```

All of this works correctly and checking/unchecking reflects on the Total Amount shown at the bottom of the page.

What I'd like to do is use the total amount that is show in the HTML below for the PayPal subscription link so that the amount is added into the 
    
line.

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="myemailaddress.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Shows & Clothes">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_description" value="Shows & Clothes">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
  <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/x-click-but20.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it\'s fast, free and secure!">
  <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="TOTAL_AMOUNT">
  <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
  <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
</form>
```

Is it possible to capture the `'totalcost'` and have it dynamically added to the `"a3"` field in the PayPal form (where it says `TOTAL_AMOUNT`) for when the customer clicks the PayPal button it already has the correct value/amount in the form?

Thank you.

Comment: Why the backslashes in `getElementById(\'Totalcost\')`?

Comment: I honestly don't know, they were already in the code, it seems to work like that...

Comment: @omega1 It can't work ... the `'` is escaped, so the string literal doesn't work. Evaluating that in the console throws a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @blueren It's **`document.getElementsByName`** and by default you'll get a **`NodeList`**.

Comment: You are right, the backslashes were there because in the original code the <head> part was in a PHP echo, I have edited the original question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`document.getElementsByName`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName). By default you'll get a [**`NodeList`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). For example:

```
var a3 = document.getElementsByName("a3")[0];
a3.value = total.toFixed(2);
```

You can easily update its value.

[image]

Something like this:

```js
var total = 0.00;

function test(item) {
  if (item.checked) {
    total += parseFloat(item.value);
  } else {
    total -= parseFloat(item.value);
  }
  document.getElementById("Totalcost").innerHTML = total.toFixed(2);

  var a3 = document.getElementsByName("a3")[0];
  a3.value = total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="myemailaddress.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Shows & Clothes">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_description" value="Shows & Clothes">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
  <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/x-click-but20.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it\'s fast, free and secure!">
  <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="TOTAL_AMOUNT">
  <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
  <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
</form>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="column-3">
      <br>
      <label class="container">
        <input type="checkbox" name="Shoes" value="2.95" onClick="test(this);">Select<span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td class="column-3">
      <br>
      <label class="container">
        <input type="checkbox" name="Clothes" value="2.95" onClick="test(this);">Select<span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<span id="Totalcost">0.00</span>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!